# How to allow controller action in CakePhp 3.x if temporary password in url passes verification?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.x

I have set up a forget password scenario where the user submits email address, gets a temporary password sent to them, and the user clicks link to be sent to a user's edit function to change password to something they can remember. I am passing the temp pass in the url.

I debugged what I could and it seems to checkout, but still won't allow a non-logged in user to access the edit method. It seems to only authorize against logged in users (you can see my problem if they forgot their password and thus cannot login).

So how would you allow access to the controller method if the temp pass matches the id param of the url?

isAuthorized function:

```
public function isAuthorized($user = null)
{
    if (isset($user['role']) && $user['role'] === 1 ) {
        return true;
    }
    if ( $this->request->action === 'edit' ) {
        $paramId = (int)$this->request->pass;
        $logged_out_user = $this->Users->get($paramId);
        if ( password_verify($this->request->query('pass'), $logged_out_user->password) === true ) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
    }
    return parent::isAuthorized($user);
}
```

sample link address: `http://localhost/site/users/edit/1?pass=o1eNbs5l7GlHlqvPAmU.`

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. I added the 'edit' action to my beforefilter so that anyone could access it whether logged in or not, then in the edit function I just added the checks, pretty simple really, but for some reason I wasn't able to think of it.

inside edit function:

```
    if ($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User')) {
        if ( $user->id === $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.id') || $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.role') === 1 ) {
            $this->Auth->allow();
        } else {
            $this->Flash->error(__('You do not have access to that page.'));
            return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
        }
    } elseif ( !empty($this->request->query('pass')) && password_verify($this->request->query('pass'), $user->password) === true ) {
        $this->Auth->setUser($user->toArray());
    } else {
        $this->Flash->error(__('You do not have access to that page.'));
        return $this->redirect(['action' => 'login']);
    }
    if ( !empty($this->request->query('pass')) && password_verify($this->request->query('pass'), $user->password) === true ) {
        $user->old_password = $this->request->query('pass');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ideally you would make it two separate actions in the controller, so that you can make your edit page only for actual user editing and your reset password page only for resetting the password.

Then just do (in your controller)...

```
public function initialize()
{
    parent::initialize();
    $this->Auth->allow(['reset_password']);
}
```

This assumes you'd make your controller reset password action like this...

```
public function reset_password($pass = false) {
   if (password_verify($pass)) {
       // show password reset form
   } else {
       $this->redirect(['action' => 'key_required_or_expired']);
   }
}
```